# How to use FckEditor in web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Q: I want to ask how to use FckEditor in my asp.net web application I download the the compressed file from their site
http://ckeditor.com/download
and extract all the files into a folder in my web application but I don't know what can I do after that..

Comment: Check here http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_SharePoint/2007/Administrators_Guide/Installation/Installing

Comment: but i want to use it with my asp.net web application not share point

Comment: So check here http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCKEditor has a howto, I'm sure. Have you read it yet?

Comment: sure , i read their instructions and apply it.http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Installation

Comment: Have you read the second part? It's called integration, here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15882

Stable ASP.Net Wrapper for the CKEditor version 3. Haven't had any trouble using it. Feels just like the old official ASP.Net Wrapper.

There is currently no officially supported CKEditor 3 ASP.Net Control. The one linked on the official page is still for version 2.